# Reading text files in java

Tags: java

I have a class Printer:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Printer {
private File file;

public Printer(String fileName) throws Exception {
    this.file = new File(fileName);
}

public void foo(String word) throws Exception {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(this.file, "UTF-8");

    while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = reader.nextLine();

        if (word.isEmpty()) {
            //System.out.println(reader.nextLine());
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
    reader.close();
}
}
```

The code above works fine. However, when I uncomment `System.out.println(reader.nextLine());` and comment out `System.out.println(line);`, why does a NoSuchElementException get thrown?

Comment: Can you show us the code which actually calls `foo()` ?

Comment: How did you get `word`?

Comment: `nextLine()` throws `NoSuchElementException` when there is no next line in provided `file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see much here which really surprises me.  Most likely, the end of the file gets reached in your `while` loop with the first call to `Scanner#nextLine()`.  Then, you make a second call which throws the exception since there is no more content to read.

```
while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
    // during the last iteration, this next call consumes the final line
    String line = reader.nextLine();

    if (word.isEmpty()) {
        // but then you call nextLine() here again, causing the exception
        //System.out.println(reader.nextLine());
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

The moral of the story here is to *not* read content from your `Scanner` without first checking that content is there.  By commenting out the above line, you removed the problem, but you should understand why it is probably good that you commented it out.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you then read two lines in each loop iteration but check only once if there is a next line. So if the file has an odd number of lines you will call `nextLine` when there is no next line which causes the exception.